# Is there a orientable surface that is topologically isomorphic to a nonorientable one?

Tags: general-topology, orientation, geometric-invariant

Is there a surface that is [orientable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability) which is topologically [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) to a nonorientable one, or is orientability a [topological invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property).

Comment: Orientability can be defined in terms of relative homology groups, see http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Orientation_of_manifolds . In particular, it is invariant under homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no: orientability is a topological invariant.

However, your question made me realise that I'd never thought about orientability for topological manifolds!  For differentiable manifolds, it's clear that orientability is diffeomorphism-invariant, because we can define it in terms of the determinant of the differential of a transition function.

For general topological manifolds, we have to first define what we mean by an orientation.  Suppose we have a continuous map $\phi : U \to V$, where $U$ and $V$ are path-connected open subsets of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Choose some point $x \in U$.  Then $x$ has some smaller neighbourhood $U' \subset U$ such that the boundary of $U'$ is homeomorphic to the $(n-1)$-sphere: $~\partial U' \cong S^{n-1}$.

$\phi$ is a homeomorphism, so we also have $\phi(\partial U') \cong S^{n-1}$.  Because $\phi$ is invertible, it induces an invertible map on homology groups $\tilde\phi: H_{n-1}(\partial U') \to H_{n-1}\big(\phi(\partial U')\big)$.  We can canonically identify both the domain and codomain of this map with $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \cong\mathbb{Z}$.  So, since $\tilde\phi$ is invertible, it must act as $\pm 1$.  If it is $+1$, we say that $\phi$ is orientation-preserving.

The last thing to check is that the above definition is independent of the point $x$ that we choose.  Given some other point $x' \in U$, choose some path $\gamma : [0,1] \to U$ such that $\gamma(0) = x$, $\gamma(1) = x'$.  Then, using the fact that $U$ is open and $\text{im}(\gamma)$ is compact, we can argue that if we started with $x'$, we would end up with a map $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ homotopic to the one we got starting with $x$.  Therefore they induce the same action on homology.

A manifold is orientable if we can find an atlas such that all the transition maps are orientation-preserving.  Given the definition, this is clearly invariant under homeomorphism.

Comment: What about spaces that are different as manifolds but different as topological spaces?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you can only define orientability for a manifold.  For a general topological space, it has no meaning.

Comment: Can a topology be given both a orientable manifold structure and a nonorientable one. There are atleast 7, 7-spheres, I believe.

Comment: There is only one *topological* manifold (up to homeomorphism of course) that you can call a '7-sphere'.  I think you're talking about differentiable structures, and I'm not sure you actually know which question you want to ask. :-)

Comment: Oh, nvm.${}{}{}$

Comment: The definition of orientable that one usually sees is applicable to differentiable manifolds.  It's manifestly diffeomorphism-invariant.  I thought you were asking whether there is a homeomorphism-invariant analogue.  There is, as demonstrated in my answer.  Where has this process gone wrong...?

Comment: I was thinking a topological space could be a manifold in a different ways. I'm a topology noob.